# How to set a maxWidth for magnificpopup in typo3

Tags: typo3, magnific-popup

I try to use magnificpopup (via jquery not as an extension) in typo3 (8.7.16)(textmediaelement) - no Problem, but :)
If the original image is smaller than the normal popup, the size of the image increases...
I tried this in constant.ts

```
styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.width = 1110m
styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.height = 800m
```

and also

```
styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.maxWidth = 1110
styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.maxHeight = 800
```

with m behind or not.

Does anyone has an idea for this problem - how I can change this behavior?

Thanks 
Volker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not magnificPopUp, but fluidStyledContent. 
in file
fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Media/Type/Image.html the ce:link.clickEnlarge hasn't got a parameter maxWidth. So I changed this link (in an own copy) to

```
<a href="{f:uri.image(src: 'fileadmin/{file.originalFile.identifier}', maxHeight: '{settings.media.popup.height}', maxWidth: '{settings.media.popup.width}')}" 
rel="{settings.detail.media.image.lightbox.rel}" class="fluidbox">...</a>
```

For this solution is fully ok - Large images are becoming smaller and other are still as they are...

cu
Volker

Answer (score 1):

Try without linkWrap and set this in TypoScript SETUP:

```
styles.content.imgtext.maxW = 1140
styles.content.imgtext.maxWInText = 1140
```

Comment: Thank you 
I did't try this because I found a soloution :)
cu
Volker